# ampersand postcss-nested not working in create-react-app

Tags: css, reactjs, nested, create-react-app, postcss

Ampersand doesn't work in styles (postcss)

package
`npm i --dev autoprefixer postcss-nested postcss-cli npm-run-all`

commands

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch:css start-js",
    "build": "npm-run-all build:css build-js",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "build:css": "postcss src/styles/main.css -o src/index.css",
    "watch:css": "postcss src/styles/main.css -o src/index.css -w",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "build-js": "react-scripts build"
}
```

*postcss.config.js* in the root

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: [require("postcss-nested"), require("autoprefixer")],
};
```

code:

- index.css

```scss
.App {
    background-color: #ffffff;

    &-header {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
}
```

- App.js

```
<div className="App">
    <header className="App-header">test</header>
</div>
```

why ampersand in code doesn't work?

Comment: Even though you have separate npm scripts for building CSS, you may be actually using `react-scripts` to compile the CSS, in which case, [it has its own PostCSS configuration](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/d960b9e38c062584ff6cfb1a70e1512509a966e7/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js#L133-L178) that you would not be able to override with a `postcss.config.js` file and this configuration does not include the `postcss-nested` plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using CRA, you need to write npm eject and only then write changes in the config that appears.

If you don't want to get all the configs when you write npm eject, then use CRACO - it allows you to create a file for configs separately